# How can I set a static ip on a fresh installation of ubuntu 20.04 on my raspberry pi?

Tags: netplan, static-ip

I have just installed `Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit server` on raspberry pi. I want to **provide a static ip to it.**

I'm thinking of adding a configuration file under `/etc/netplan/` (following [these examples](https://netplan.io/examples/)), but inside `/etc/netplan/` I see a file: `50-cloud-init.yaml` with the following comment

> This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
> # to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
> # network configuration capabilities, write a file
> # /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
> # network: {config: disabled}

I have two questions:

- Am I supposed to create this: `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg` before creating the static address yaml file under `/etc/netplan/` ?
- Should I prefer the `/run/netplan/` directory for adding my static address configration?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just create the file `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` with the correct configuration for your server.

This should get read before the `50-cloud-init.yaml` since according to this https://linuxconfig.org/netplan-network-configuration-tutorial-for-beginners

> Inside each of these directories configurations are created using
> files with the .yaml extension which are processed in lexicographical
> order, regardless of the directory they are in.

You may need to disable cloud init
[How to get rid of cloud-init?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539277/how-to-get-rid-of-cloud-init)

Some details here [01-netcfg.yaml and 50-cloud-init.yaml both exist - can't find one IP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227058/01-netcfg-yaml-and-50-cloud-init-yaml-both-exist-cant-find-one-ip)

Comment: According to the comments of the file, it seems like it is auto-generated on each reboot.

Comment: I added the the new file and now I have two ips under eth0 (`ip address` command). The dynamic and the static.

Answer (score 0):

@Jannis
I ran into that situation as well (2 IPs for eth0, one DHCP and the other static).

Apparently netplan is executing each yaml file in /etc/netplan and dutifully assigning an IP to the interface as instructed in each file.

I didn't add or touch any other yaml files in /etc/netplan and did my static IP mods to 50-cloud-init.yaml.

Rebooted and now I only see my static IP assignment.